# How do you make an image clickable so that a different image of the same size replaces it with each click? (on a website page)

Tags: image, click

I have multiple images on each page. I want to be able to click on an image and have a different image replace it (a totally different image, not an image already featured on the page). I would like to be able to click the image multiple times and have different hand-selected images replace the following image after each click.

For example, there is an image of a dog. I want to be able to click the image and have it become an image of a cat. Then I want to click it again and have it become an image of a mouse. The image that would show up would depend on how many times the image has been clicked. I want all the images to be the same size.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Check this out]

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("img").click(function() {
    var imgs = $("#demo img");
    var activeImage = $("img.active").index();
    var nextImage = $("img.active").index() + 1;

    if(activeImage == imgs.length - 1) {
      nextImage = 0;   
    }
   imgs.eq(nextImage).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active')

  })
})
```

```css
#demo {
            position: relative;
        }
        #demo img {
            position: absolute;
            left: 0px;
            top: 0px;
            opacity: 0;
            width: 400px;
            cursor: pointer;
            transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
        }
        #demo img.active {
            opacity: 1;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
  <img src="https://s11.postimg.org/5m39wc1yr/image.jpg" class="active">
  <img src="https://s11.postimg.org/ndewashdf/image.jpg">
  <img src="https://s11.postimg.org/5c0cqqcqb/image.jpg">
  <img src="https://s11.postimg.org/3lhbp8v77/image.jpg">
</div>
```